# Does \ifx compare conditionals differently than other tokens?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

I'm getting an unexpected result with parsing loop that uses `\ifx`.  My understanding is that, for control-sequences, `\ifx` looks for "top level" equivalence and the same modifiers like `\long`.  In other words, there's no ordinary expansion.  However, if one of the tokens being compared is a conditional like `\ifnum`, then the loop fails.  Why?

Minimal example follows.  You can see that any cs token seems to compare just fine except for `\ifnum`.  If that token is removed, the loop ends happily with the `\b` comparison.

```
\def\b{\undefined}
\def\aloop#1{%
  \ifx#1\b
    \wlog{true: \noexpand#1}%
    \let\next\empty
  \else
    \wlog{false: \noexpand#1}%
    \let\next\aloop
  \fi
  \next}

\aloop x~#{y}\alpha\relax\end\ifnum\b
```

Results:

```
false: x
false: ~
false: ##
false: y
false: \alpha
false: \relax
false: \end

! Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 16.
<inserted text>
                \fi
<to be read again>
...
```

Answer (score 5):

You've just fallen into a trap that has caught many of us. ;-) So you are not the first:

- `\if..`-`\else`-`\fi`-matching is independent of group nesting.
- When you place `\if...\else...\fi`-constructs into a macro definition you need to do that in a way where it is ensured that at the time of expanding the macro no components of these `\if...\else...\fi`-constructs can erroneously be matched/"counterbalanced" by combinations of unmatched tokens `\if..`/`\else`/`\fi` that probably come from the macro's arguments.

---

To the question *"Does \ifx compare conditionals differently than other tokens"*?:

The `\ifx`-primitive causes TeX to compare (without triggering expansion on them beforehand) the meaning of the next token with the meaning of the next but one token and to evaluate whether the condition of these meanings being equal is fulfilled. It does so also in case some of these two tokens are conditional-primitives or unmatched `\else` or unmatched `\fi` or are tokens defined in terms of `\outer` or are unbalanced curly braces.

*(Strictly spoken the following is not a statement about what `\ifx` "does"/strictly spoken the following is not a statement about what TeX does when actually carrying out `\ifx`. The following is a statement about what TeX does when skipping branches of `\if.. ...\else...\fi`-conditional-expressions.)*

However, when it comes to comparing via `\ifx` unmatched `\if..`- or `\else`- or `\fi`-tokens, be aware that in case such a comparison is placed inside another `\if..`-expression's skipped branch all `\if..`/`\else`/`\fi` tokens in that skipped branch are taken into account for the `\if..`-`\else`-`\fi`-matching for finding the `\else` or the `\fi` which denotes the end that skipped branch. With all primitives for `\if..`-forking the routine for detecting the `\else` or the `\fi` which terminates a branch which is to be skipped does not check whether an `\if..`- or an `\else`- or a `\fi`-token itself is the argument of an `\ifx`-token.

E.g.,
`\iffalse \ifx\ifx Z y\fi\fi This is not printed.\else This is printed.\fi\bye`
yields: **This is printed.**

E.g.,
`\iftrue This is printed. \else \ifx\ifx Z y\fi\fi This is not printed. \fi  This is printed, too.\bye`
yields: **This is printed. This is printed, too.**

---

*What happens when TeX processes your code:*

With `\ifnum` as argument `\aloop`'s `\ifx`-condition is false.

Thus the true-branch is skipped until finding matching `\else` or `\fi`.

Hereby `\if..\else..\fi` inside the true-branch that is to be skipped are matched, too, while `\if..\else..\fi`-matching is independent from group-nesting.

Thus the first `\ifnum` coming from `\aloop`'s argument matches the `\else` coming from `\aloop`'s macro-definition—the `\else`-branch coming from `\aloop`'s macro definition is considered a component of an `\ifnum...\else...\fi` expression (whose `\ifnum` comes from `\aloop`'s argument) nested inside the to-be-skipped `\ifx`'s-true branch. While skipping that `\else`-branch, the second `\ifnum` coming from `\aloop`'s macro-argument is found. It is matched with the `\fi` from `\aloop`'s macro-definition. So both a matching `\fi` for the first `\ifnum` coming from `\aloop`'s macro-argument and a matching `\fi` for the `\ifx` coming from `\aloop`'s macro-definition are still missing. And skipping things that are considered components of `\ifx`'s true-branch goes on, thus `\next`, being the last token coming from the macro-definition and tokens coming after that are skipped. Probably skipping goes on until reaching the end of the file or the command `\bye` which is defined `\outer` and where the message about incomplete `\ifx` is raised.

`\aloop\ifnum` yields:

```tex
\ifx\ifnum\b %<- The condition is false, thus the true branch is not evaluated but skipped.
             %  \if...\else..\fi are matched while skipping.
             % Brace-nesting is independent from \if...\else..\fi-matching.
  \wlog{true: \noexpand\ifnum}%<- This is the 1st \ifnum
  \let\next\empty
\else %<- This matches the 1st \ifnum
  \wlog{false: \noexpand\ifnum}%<- This is the 2nd \ifnum
  \let\next\aloop
\fi%<- This matches the 2nd \ifnum
\next

% A \fi matching the 1st \ifnum is still not found here.
% A \fi matching the \ifx is still not found here.
% This situation is while skipping components of the true-branch of
% an \ifx-condition.
% Thus the error-message about incomplete `\ifx` when reaching
% either the end of the file or the next token that is defined
% in terms of `\outer`. (E.g., \bye is defined in terms of \outer.)
```

Instead try:

```tex
\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}%
\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}%
\def\b{\undefined}%
\def\aloop#1{%
  \ifx\b#1\expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
  {%
    \wlog{true: \detokenize{#1}}%
  }{%
    \wlog{false: \detokenize{#1}}%
    \aloop
  }%
}%

\aloop x~#{y}\alpha\relax\end\ifnum\b

\bye
```

I also changed from `\ifx#1\b` to `\ifx\b#1` to make sure that the loop is not fooled by arguments like `{\same\same}` where you would get `\ifx\same\same\b` which is true (and leads to attempts at evaluating `\b`...).
But this still is not perfect because the loop might also stop/go the true-branch in case the argument is not a single token whose meaning equals the meaning of `\b` but a leading token whose meaning equals the meaning of `\b` trailed by some more tokens that end up in the true-branch so that attempts at evaluating them take place.
A malevolent user could still provide some tokens containing unbalanced `\if..`- or `\else` or `\fi`-expressions as `#1` in order to provoke unpredictable behavior and unexpected error messages.

So you might be better off doing the check for `\b` not via `\ifx` but via delimited arguments, for example:

```tex
\long\def\fot#1#2{#1}% first of two
\long\def\sot#1#2{#2}% second of two
\long\def\gobbletoexclam#1!{}%
\long\def\CsbFork#1!\b!#2#3!!!!{#2}%
\long\def\aloop#1{%
   \ifcat$\detokenize\expandafter{\gobbletoexclam#1!}$\expandafter\fot\else\expandafter\sot\fi
   {\CsbFork!#1!{\fot}!\b!{\sot}!!!!}{\sot}%
   {\wlog{This is the stop-condition \string\b: \detokenize{#1}}}%
   {\wlog{This is not the stop condition: \detokenize{#1}}\aloop}%
}%

\aloop x~#{y}\alpha\relax\end{\b\b}{\same\same}!{!\b!}\ifnum\b

\bye
```

```
This is not the stop condition: x
This is not the stop condition: ~
This is not the stop condition: ##
This is not the stop condition: y
This is not the stop condition: \alpha 
This is not the stop condition: \relax 
This is not the stop condition: \end 
This is not the stop condition: \b \b 
This is not the stop condition: \same \same 
This is not the stop condition: !
This is not the stop condition: !\b !
This is not the stop condition: \ifnum 
This is the stop-condition \b: \b
```

This way the loop stops when its argument is a single token `\b`. It must be exactly `\b`, not a token whose meaning equals the meaning of `\b`.

Or have TeX iterate until some list-argument-holding argument is empty:

```tex
\long\def\noo#1{}% none of one
\long\def\foo#1{#1}% first of one
\long\def\fot#1#2{#1}% second of two
\long\def\initiatealoop#1{\aloop{#1}#1}%
\long\def\aloop#1#2{%
  % \fot is needed in case #1 has trailing spaces...
  \ifcat$\detokenize\expandafter{\fot#1{}{}}$%
    \expandafter\noo
  \else
    \expandafter\foo
  \fi
   {%
      \wlog{argument: \detokenize{#2}}%
      \expandafter\aloop\expandafter{\noo#1}%
   }%
}%

\initiatealoop{x~#{y}\alpha\relax\end\ifnum}%

\bye
```

Comment: That's a really great explanation, thank you!  Also, please forgive my slow response.  Got a new computer and forgot to add back certain accounts.

Comment: good suggestion to switch `\ifx\b#1 `.  I'm curious, though, why the space after `#1`?  Is it a remnant of my code perhaps?

Comment: @DanLevin As I changed your code in this regard it definitely cannot be called a remnant of your code. It is a bug introduced by me. Thank you for drawing my attention towards it. I just edited my answer and removed that space.

Comment: @DanLevin *"Got a new computer and forgot to add back certain accounts."*
I know how it is ;-) My current favorite machine had some capacitors on the motherboard pop after only eight years, but in our country they have delivery problems and crazy prices at the moment.  So I went to the collection point for electronic waste and looked for old circuit boards with the needed components. Back at home I grabbed the soldering iron like in the old days and felt like I was 16 again. Just a little more shaky and more reliant on the magnifying glass. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
false: x
false: ~
false: #
false: y
false: \alpha
false: \relax
false: \end
false: \ifnum
true: \b
```

if `#1`is `\ifx` then you need to skip over

`\wlog{true: \noexpand\ifx}%`

and that fails. You could hide it like so, which makes the log shown above.

```
\def\b{\undefined}
\def\aloop#1{%
\edef\qqq{\string#1}%
  \ifx#1\b
    \wlog{true: \qqq}%
    \let\next\empty
  \else
    \wlog{false: \qqq}%
    \let\next\aloop
  \fi
  \next}

\aloop x~#{y}\alpha\relax\end\ifnum\b


\bye
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.  And please forgive my slow response.  I got a new computer and forgot to restore certain accounts.

Answer (score 2):

#### tl;dr

Your

```
\aloop\ifnum
```

becomes

```
\ifx\ifnum\b\wlog{true: \noexpand\ifnum}…\else…\fi
```

and TeX skips over the true text, but “of course” it matches the `\fi` with `\ifnum`.

---

A bit more detailed. A primitive conditional has the form

```
<IF> <test> <true text> \else <false text> \fi
```

where `<IF>` stands for one among `\if`, `\ifcat`, `\ifnum`, `\ifdim`, `\ifodd`, `\ifx`, `\iftrue`, `\iffalse`. (There's also `\ifcase`, but it's a different beast.)

The `<test>` is the shortest list of tokens that makes it possible to determine whether the condition is true or false. The test for `\iftrue` and `\iffalse` is empty. TeX does macro expansion when processing the first five commands in the list above; for instance, after `\ifnum` it wants to see an integer, then a comparison token among `=<>` and another integer.

The `<true text>` is the shortest list of tokens that's balanced with respect to the conditionals therein and ends at `\else` or `\fi` balancing the `<IF>` that's being processed.

In the case of `\ifx` *no* macro expansion is performed and the `<test>` consists of the two following tokens, whatever they are. They're not interpreted in any way, just compared with each other.

In your case you have

```
\ifx\ifnum\b\wlog{true: \noexpand\ifnum}…\else…\fi
```

where `\ifnum` and `\b` are different, according to the comparison rules of `\ifx`. The ` is

```
\wlog{true: \noexpand\ifnum}…
```

and here is the problem. TeX skips over the `<true text>` without doing any interpretation, *but taking conditionals into account*. So TeX *sees* `\ifnum` and balances it with `\else` and `\fi`. The `<true text>` and `<false text>` are *not* determined when the `<IF>` is scanned, but dynamically as the processing goes on.

And, to make the job funner, braces aren't taken into account. For instance, `latex.ltx` is full of things such as

```
{\ifnum0=`}\fi
\ifnum0=`{\fi}
```

that exploit this property in order to add, in particular circumstances, unbalanced braces.

Comment: I appreciate the good advice.